# VBA Multiple Insert statements but only partial adds

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am having a issue where I have some VBA Code set up to add a number of records into my tables. the code compiles without a problem and does not trigger any errors when run, however when I go back and look at the records in my tables only about half of the neccessary records have been created

here is the code

```
    Private Sub btnAddEnt_Click()
Dim strEnt As String
Dim strRev As String
Dim strDir As String
Dim strInd As String
Dim strDep As String
Dim strARev As String
Dim strADir As String
Dim strAInd As String
Dim strADep As String
strEnt = "INSERT INTO EntList (EntityID, BusinessUnit, EntityName, Location, Client,Dept) " & _
         "VALUES ('" & Me.EntityID & "', '" & Me.BusinessUnit & "', '" & Me.EntityName & "', '" & Me.Location & "', '" & Me.Client & "', '" & Me.Dept & "');"
strRev = "INSERT INTO ForcastTrans (Location, Client, Department, Account, EntityID, Description, Month1, Month2, Month3, Month4, Month5, Month6, Month7, Month8, Month9, Month10, Month11, Month12) " & _
         "VALUES ('" & Me.Location & "', '" & Me.Client & "', '" & Me.Dept & "', '4151 SET UP', '" & Me.EntityID & "', 'Default', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);"
strDir = "INSERT INTO ForcastTrans (Location, Client, Department, Account, EntityID, Description, Month1, Month2, Month3, Month4, Month5, Month6, Month7, Month8, Month9, Month10, Month11, Month12) " & _
         "VALUES ('" & Me.Location & "', '" & Me.Client & "', '" & Me.Dept & "', '5855 OTHER', '" & Me.EntityID & "', 'Default', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);"
strInd = "INSERT INTO ForcastTrans (Location, Client, Department, Account, EntityID, Description, Month1, Month2, Month3, Month4, Month5, Month6, Month7, Month8, Month9, Month10, Month11, Month12) " & _
         "VALUES ('" & Me.Location & "', '" & Me.Client & "', '" & Me.Dept & "', '6055 SALARIES/WAGES - OTHER', '" & Me.EntityID & "', 'Default', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);"
strDep = "INSERT INTO ForcastTrans (Location, Client, Department, Account, EntityID, Description, Month1, Month2, Month3, Month4, Month5, Month6, Month7, Month8, Month9, Month10, Month11, Month12) " & _
         "VALUES ('" & Me.Location & "', '" & Me.Client & "', '" & Me.Dept & "', '6950 DEPRECIATION', '" & Me.EntityID & "', 'Default', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);"
strARev = "INSERT INTO ActualTrans (Location, Client, Department, Account, EntityID, Month1, Month2, Month3, Month4, Month5, Month6, Month7, Month8, Month9, Month10, Month11, Month12) " & _
          "VALUES ('" & Me.Location & "', '" & Me.Client & "', '" & Me.Dept & "', '4151 SET UP', '" & Me.EntityID & "', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);"
strADir = "INSERT INTO ActualTrans (Location, Client, Department, Account, EntityID, Month1, Month2, Month3, Month4, Month5, Month6, Month7, Month8, Month9, Month10, Month11, Month12) " & _
          "VALUES ('" & Me.Location & "', '" & Me.Client & "', '" & Me.Dept & "', '5855 OTHER', '" & Me.EntityID & "', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);"
strAInd = "INSERT INTO ActualTrans (Location, Client, Department, Account, EntityID, Month1, Month2, Month3, Month4, Month5, Month6, Month7, Month8, Month9, Month10, Month11, Month12) " & _
          "VALUES ('" & Me.Location & "', '" & Me.Client & "', '" & Me.Dept & "', '6055 SALARIES/WAGES - OTHER', '" & Me.EntityID & "', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);"
strADep = "INSERT INTO ActualTrans (Location, Client, Department, Account, EntityID, Month1, Month2, Month3, Month4, Month5, Month6, Month7, Month8, Month9, Month10, Month11, Month12) " & _
          "VALUES ('" & Me.Location & "', '" & Me.Client & "', '" & Me.Dept & "', '6950 DEPRECIATION', '" & Me.EntityID & "', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);"
Debug.Print strEnt
Debug.Print strRev
Debug.Print strDir
Debug.Print strInd
Debug.Print strDep
Debug.Print strARev
Debug.Print strADir
Debug.Print strAInd
Debug.Print strADep
CurrentDb.Execute strEnt
CurrentDb.Execute strRev
CurrentDb.Execute strDir
CurrentDb.Execute strInd
CurrentDb.Execute strDep
CurrentDb.Execute strARev
CurrentDb.Execute strADir
CurrentDb.Execute strAInd
CurrentDb.Execute strADep
DoCmd.Close
```

As you can see I inserted the Debug.Print lines trying to figure out what was going on but all of the sql strings are good. However when this section of code is finished executing the records for (strInd, strDep, strAInd, and strADep) do not exist in my tables.

Is there some step that I am missing or should include to stablize this so that all the records get created as intended?

Comment: You could try inserting `DoEvents` between some of those execute commands.  It's a mediocre fix but, if it made a change, would indicate something.  Your code is crying out for refactoring ... but that's just me being a complainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add code around the executes to see what the error is, most likely something from SQL

```
On Error GoTo Err_Execute 
Currentdb.Execute strInd
On Error GoTo 0 

' etc ...

Exit Sub

Err_Execute: 

 ' Notify user of any errors that result from 
 ' executing the query. 
 If DBEngine.Errors.Count > 0 Then 
 For Each errLoop In DBEngine.Errors 
 MsgBox "Error number: " & errLoop.Number & vbCr & _ 
 errLoop.Description 
 Next errLoop 
 End If 

 Resume Next 

End Sub
```

My VBA is very rusty, but this should get you started so you can see what the error is...   A quick guess, I would check the length of the description field in the ForecastTran table.  Only thing I can see is that those values look slightly longer than the others than worked.

Comment: Where would you recommend that I add the error handler? above the strings or at the bottom of the code?

Comment: Sparky's rusty code is better than my fresh code :-)  I made some edits to indicate the general location of things.  If no err, `Exit Sub` takes you out so you never reach the trapping methods at bottom.

Comment: That did the trick it let me identify a missing value in one of my reference tables as soon as I correct that the issue which was key violations went away and the code executed perfectly. thank you very much